# Filter Array with dictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nspredicate

There is an Array with each element being a `NSDictionary`.

```
NSMutableArray *mutArr = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Person *person in persons) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:person.name, @"name", person.email, @"email", nil];
    [mutArr addObject:dict];
}

self.arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutArr];
```

How to filer the `arr` with name or email contains string `@"filter string"` by using `filterArrayUsingPredicate:` method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Please see the below example:

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"filter string" forKey:@"email"]];   // you can also do same for Name key... 
    NSArray *filteredarray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email == %@)", @"filter string"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

```
var customerNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"alagu","MiddleName":"prabhu"];
var clientNameDict = ["firstName":"Selva","LastName":"kumar","MiddleName":"m"];
var employeeNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"prabhu","MiddleName":"kp"];

var attributeValue = "karthi";

var arrNames:Array = [customerNameDict,clientNameDict,employeeNameDict];

var namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName like %@",attributeValue);

let filteredArray = arrNames.filter { namePredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
println("names = ,\(filteredArray)");
```