# Filter data from array of Dictionary using predicate iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nspredicate

Hello guys i have an array of dictionary, can you guys tell me how can i filter this data based on dictionary keys.

```
(
    {
    "mall_id" = M0550;
    "mall_name" = "Amrita Shopping Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0509;
    "mall_name" = "Ashoka Market";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0943;
    "mall_name" = "Biju Pattnaik Commercial Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0457;
    "mall_name" = "BMC Bhawani Mall";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0460;
    "mall_name" = "BMC Keshari Mall";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0571;
    "mall_name" = "BMC Market Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0453;
    "mall_name" = "Forum Mart";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0609;
    "mall_name" = "Indradhanu Market";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0558;
    "mall_name" = "Kalyani Plaza Market Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0463;
    "mall_name" = "Maa Barabhuja Mall";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0553;
    "mall_name" = "Mahaveer Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0570;
    "mall_name" = "Market Building";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0452;
    "mall_name" = "Pal Heights Mall";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0466;
    "mall_name" = "Priyadarshini Market Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0677;
    "mall_name" = "Ruchika Market";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0504;
    "mall_name" = "Shubham Market Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0564;
    "mall_name" = "Subhadra Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0559;
    "mall_name" = "Sultania Shopping Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0552;
    "mall_name" = "Tathastu Complex";
},
    {
    "mall_id" = M0568;
    "mall_name" = "Western Tower Market Building";
}
)
```

what i want to achieve, whenever i type anything in search bar it will check mall_name key and return matching values in array.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Array with dictionaries using NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084318/filter-array-with-dictionaries-using-nspredicate)

Comment: you can check it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084318/filter-array-with-dictionaries-using-nspredicate

Comment: I have tried that link but not working for me. @SaurabhPrajapati

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will give you your desired output

**Objective - C**

```
NSArray *filteredData = [yourArrayContainingDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_name contains[c] %@)", searchText]];
```

**Swift**

```
let filteredData = yourArrayContainingDictionary.filter{
    let string = $0["mall_name"] as! String

    return string.hasPrefix("searchText")
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I have face this similar issue, this solution worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Try this one. (Predicate works like SQL queries)

**Obj C**

```
 NSArray *filterArray = [sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_name contains[c] %@)", searchText]];
```

**Swift**

```
var filterArray: [Any] = sourceArray.filter { NSPredicate(format: "(mall_name contains[c] %@)", searchText).evaluate(with: $0) }
```

It will return entries whose name contain the search string.

Answer (score 4):

**Use this for you solution**

```
NSArray *filtered = [yourArrayOfDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_name contains[c] %@)", <your search text from search bar>]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my 2 versions using predicate and the classical one:

```
let dict = [
    [
        "mall_id": 1,
        "mall_name": "Amrita Shopping Complex"
    ],
    [
        "mall_id": 2,
        "mall_name": "Ashoka Market"
    ] ]

// Example using Predicate

let mallNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mall_name contains %@", "Ashoka")
let filteredWithPredicate = (dict as NSArray).filtered(using: mallNamePredicate)

// Classical filter example 
let filtered = dict.filter { pair in
    guard let mallName = pair["mall_name"] as? String else { return false }
    return mallName.hasPrefix("Ashoka")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this gives you an array of dictionaries with `requiredMallID` only

```
 NSArray *filtered = [array_with_dict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_id == %@)", requiredMallID]];
```

For example,

```
NSArray *filtered = [array_with_dict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_id == %@)", "M0550"]];
```

gives you

```
    (
        {
        "mall_id" = M0550;
        "mall_name" = "Amrita Shopping Complex";
    } 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *filtered = [arrName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_name == %@)", requiredMailName]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSArray *filtered = [array_with_dict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_id == %@)", wantedMallID]];
```

Answer (score 1):

More swifty way of doing this would be something like

```
let mallArray  = [
    [
        "mall_id": "M0550",
        "mall_name": "Amrita Shopping Complex"
    ],
    [
        "mall_id": "M0509",
        "mall_name": "Ashoka Market"
    ]
]

func isMatching(_ searchText: String) -> [[String: Any]] {
    let filteredArray = mallArray.filter {
        return $0["mall_name"]!.contains(searchText)
    }
    return filteredArray
}

let malls = isMatching("Ashoka")
print(malls)
```

Answer (score 0):

He wants to search on *partial* matches on mall_*name*, not mall_id, continually updating as users type into the search bar. So correct solutions are those with this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mall_name contains[c] %@)", searchText]
```

... not 'mall_id', not @"(xxx == %@)", and the 'contains[c]' gives him *case-insensitive* matches.